# rails and multi dbs, using establish_connection on the fly to route to the correct database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to structure my database in such a way that certain tables (that don't have any relationships with other tables, so no joins required) have to be put on seperate mysql databases.

I know each model has a `establish_connection` property.

What I want to do:

1. I will fetch 10 rows from a particular model, based on a clientID.

The clientID will determine which database this model will be fetched from.

I want to have this database routing logic baked into the model logic somehow.

Is this possible?

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: i am leaning towards using postgresql, but you can give advice on mysql if you want.

Answer (score 7):

You can point individual models to different databases using establish_connection in your models. See [here for examples](http://pullmonkey.com/2008/4/21/ruby-on-rails-multiple-database-connections/).

If you want a single model to access multiple databases based on an attribute, you probably need to use database sharding, for example, with [DataFabric](https://github.com/fiveruns/data_fabric) or [ShardTheLove](https://github.com/mixonic/ShardTheLove).

Comment: why do I have to use those libs if I want to choose based on an attribute, can't I just do something in the constructor or something? I was hoping this would be a 'lean' modification :)

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if this can help you :

https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2

This allows you to do connections and requests like this :

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root")
results = client.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE group='githubbers'")
```

Comment: I've had different issue, but this solution helped. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you need is 'Sharding' support

Unfortunately, ActiveRecord doesn't have this built in. There are a bunch of gems that hack in Sharding support

The gem 'octopus' seems promising. See https://github.com/tchandy/octopus

**Note: I haven't used octopus myself**

If you are willing to go one step further, I recommend **Sequel** ( http://sequel.rubyforge.org/ ) which is a stable, feature-rich ORM that I have used before.

The documentation is excellent. What you need is http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/sharding_rdoc.html

It might take sometime to get used to Sequel if you are accustomed to AR 2.x. There is a nice migration guide. See http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/active_record_rdoc.html

Hoping this helps